# In c# how do I remove the halo from a transparent splash screen

Tags: c#

I have a splash screen that is black with white text and a limeGreen background (for transparency key).

the splash screen is part of a c# project.

the image is very irregular in shape and when i run the splash screen although the transparency works i observe a halo around the outside in limegreen (approx 1px).

what can i do to stop the halo effect?

thanks

Comment: [Windows Forms Transparent Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33531201/3110834).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the image again and don't do antialiasing towards the green. The TransparencyKey property works by making all pixels with an *exact* color transparent, which means if you have antialiasing for making the shape smoother it won't work and leave those half-green/half-content pixels there.

Comment: thanks for the response, the image in question has grass! ... how do i stop the antialiasing in photoshop?