# Floating icon above desktop

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm writing a C# application and I want it to have a floating icon over the desktop (like the Facebook messenger in mobile).

I've been searching the internet but couldn't find anything useful. Any articles? Ideas?

Comment: You need to create a form with `FormBorderStyle` set to `None`. Also if you want to use an image for your form, Set the `BackgroundImage` and the set the `BackColor` and `TransparencyKey` of form.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a form without title bar and border and use an image as background of your form. Also make area around the image, transparent. Then make the form movable.

- Set the form `FormBorderStyle` to `None`
- Set the form `TopMost` to `true`
- You can also set `ShowInTaskbar` to false.
- Set an image as `BackgroundImage` and set `BackgroundImageLayout` to `Center`
- Set a suitable `BackColor` for form, for example if your `BackGroundImage` has `Magenta` color around, set the `BackColor` of form to `Magenta`.
- Set the `TransparencyKey` of form to the color you choose for `BackColor`

This way you will have a shaped form, for example a circle form (if your background image was circle shape).

Then to make the form move by dragging with left mouse button, write this code:

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Here is the image used:

[image]

And as you see in the result below, now we have a floating icon above other windows:

[image]

To have a high quality Icon with more smooth edges take a look at this post:

- [C# Windows Form Transparent Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33531201/3110834)

Comment: Good practice, however I lost the mouse left click events how to avoid this?

Comment: @SHADOW.NET As an option, you can start dragging on mouse move, and make sure the distance of the current mouse position and start point is bugger than a specific value, for example 32.