# Image without background on winform

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I have an image without background on a winforms application.

So that you only can see the image, without a form or something.

I now tried to set the Background Color and Transparency key to the same color but that results to this:

[image: Screenshot]

I also search the web but I didn't found really usefull answers...

So is there another way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floating icon above desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481970/floating-icon-above-desktop/34482683#34482683)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using png with transparency for image and real transparency for the form by overriding `CreateParams` to allow transparency.

Provlem on your screenshot is caused by mixing original background color with image. After mixing the color doesn't match transparency key, so you get such border.

The other solution can be to draw the image having no transparency without scaling and antialiasing.