# How to make a transparent form with a high definition?

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, winforms, transparency

I am trying to make a transparent application, but the results come out with grainy edges, like this example in the image below.
Is there any way to remove this green outline?

```
        Me.BackColor = LimeGreen
        Me.TransparencyKey = Me.BackColor
```

Error SS:           [image: Green outline]

Original Image: [image]

Comment: There are a few methods, this is one of the more common: [Windows Form Transparent Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33531201/7444103).

Answer (score 0):

A couple ways:

1. Use a background color that is very near to the while border color.  Then the thin outline will be much less visible.
2. Use [Layered Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows).