# How to remove the border of a transparent Image in a PictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I was trying to put a transparent image on a transparent Form.
As you can see the image has a black outline. I saw that someone solved this with the Paint Event on the PictureBox. I tried it too but nothing.

[image]

The color of the outline is based on the Form Color.

Comment: [Windows Form Transparent Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33531201/7444103)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't so much have a black outline as "it has an outline that is black with a slight transparency" which means it isn't the color your form is using as its transparency key - which is quite a primitive way of making parts of a form transparent - it cannot cope with partially transparent pixels

Use the advice posted by Jimi in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33531201/7444103