# How do I show an image with a glow on a transparent form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this [transparent circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTvxy.png) with a glow around it and I am trying to put it on a transparent form that uses a transparency key, but the glowing part of the image shows the transparency key like this:
[image: what the form shows]

**Is there anyway to fix this?**

Edit:
Here is the code I am using

```cs
// This makes the form transparent
this.BackColor = Color.Coral;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Coral;

// I have the circle in a picture box like this
picturebox.Size = Properties.Resources.image.Size;
picturebox.Image = Properties.Resources.image;
```

Comment: What UI technology are you using? Winforms? WPF? Can you show the code for making the form transparent and loading the button?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear early I am using Winforms to make this and I added the code above.

Comment: You need a per-pixel-alpha Layered Form. See [Windows Form Transparent Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33531201/7444103)