Winforms Graphics.DrawImage Transparent bleeding
I am trying to code an overlay that you can click through. I am using Graphics.DrawImage inside of a Paint Event. But I get some weird results...
What I get

What i expect

Original Image

Result with InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
Code:
public overlay()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.ClientSize = new Size(1920, 1080);
    this.ShowIcon = false;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    this.BackColor = Color.Lime;
    this.TransparencyKey = Color.Lime;
    this.TopMost = true;
    this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.overlay_Paint);
}

private void overlay_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int size = 20;
    var img = Bitmap.FromFile(@"Icon.png");
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, (this.Width / 2) - (size / 2), (this.Height / 2) - (size / 2), size, size);
}

Any help is appreciated!

Could you please provide a [mcve] that takes your source image and draws it on to a new bitmap? Basically filling in this code: using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(size, size)) { using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) { using (var img = Bitmap.FromFile(@"KyE4z.png")) { ... } } }.

NearestNeighbor

@TaW NearestNeighbor makes it a bit better but not great, still loads of green

@Enigmativity Isn't that what I did in the original question?

I think you'll need some extra elbow grease (more than just BackColor and TransparencyKey) to get the full-alpha "glow" effect - the green is the glow of your image being blended with that lime green, creating a matte border.

@Sneaky - No. I could not recreate your issue. I need a [mcve] that I can run to see what result you are getting. Then I can verifiably fix it and post an answer.

@Enigmativity I edited the original question's code block, and it is now reproducible just download the original image

https://stackoverflow.com/q/33530623/14171304 ?

I think you original file is fuzzy. Look at the color count! Is it 2 or is it more? (Irfanview will tell you)

@Sneaky - Your code works pretty well when you replace Color.Lime and use Color.Black instead.
